# Having issue validating street address with some letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a street address with the following function which works fine for all English letters. But it does not accept these letters `ö, Ö, ä, Ä`. How can I change the following function so that it accepts these letters too?

```
validateAddress = function (val) {
        var streetRegex = /^[\w+\s]+\d+,\s*[\s\w]+$/;
        if (streetRegex.test(val)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match? There is a vast array of formats for street addresses, a general parser isn't a simple task and probably not suitable for a single regular expression.

Comment: this pattern `street näme 18, city`

Comment: Your problem is that `\w` matches a [character set](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.12) that doesn't include ö, Ö and so on.

Comment: By the way, what if streetname is Street 32 b 2, City

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers should be able to handle those characters in the regex. Check out [this example](http://jsbin.com/ujefip/1/edit) on Chrome or Firefox.

```
var str = 'öabÖcdäefgÄh';
console.log( str.match(/[öä]/gi) ); //=> ["ö", "Ö", "ä", "Ä"]
```

But you can always convert those chars to ascii or unicode and use that instead:

```
function toAscii( str ) {
  return str.replace(/./g, function( char ) {
    return '\\x'+ char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}

// Use RegExp constructor
var regex = new RegExp('...'+ toAscii('ä') +'...');
```

Comment: I have a modern chrome but my function above does not work for me whereas your example does.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, `\w` doesn't match special characters. You need to add the characters you want to your regex like in my example. If you need to validate many more then you can create a range by looking at an ascii table and figuring out the first an last characters for example `[À-ÿ]`

Comment: do you mean I need to add letters `öÖäÄ` instead of `\w`?

Comment: Not instead, _in addition_ `[\wöÖäÄ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
/^\D+\d+,\D+$/
```

It works on ä and ö chars also.

Comment: Edited before you said it. =D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that \w matches a character set that doesn't include ö, Ö and so on. You need to think of another way to match character ranges for allowed characters. Perhaps you should go the other way and match non–digit characters:

```
var re = /\D+\d+,\s*[\s\w]+$/
```

Otherwise you will need to specify various character ranges depending on the alphabets that you intend to support (i.e. those for different languages). I think regular expressions are based on ASCII, which is based on the English alphabet.